# how to stored procedure that uses 2 or more 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i ihave here 3 tables:

```
Tapes                                 

TapesID   Title    Qty
T1      BatDog     3
T2      UnderCat   2
T3      IronMouse  1
T4      Boys Zone  1
T5      RoboCat    1

Borrow_Details

BTransID    TSpecID Qty
BT1111      TS1     1
BT1111      TS2     1
BT1111      TS3     1
BT1112      TS1     1
BT1113      TS4     1
BT1113      TS5     1
BT1114      TS1     1
BT1114      TS6     1
BT1115      TS7     1

Tape_Specific_ID

TapesID TSpecID
     T1 TS1
     T1 TS2
     T1 TS3
     T2 TS4
     T2 TS5
     T3 TS6
     T4 TS7
     T5 TS8
     T5 TS9
```

1. how to create a stored procedure that displays the title of the tape and number of times that a specific tape has been borrowed. The input to the procedure is only the specific id. The named of procedure should be list_title_ntimes

my code but for no. 1:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE list_title_ntimes (IN my_id VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN

 SELECT Title FROM Tapes AND TSpecID from Tapes_SPecID WHERE ID = my_id;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but this doesn't work..

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question

Comment: And show [what they've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: ive already updated my question and posted my code...

Comment: I don't understand why you are going for a stored procedure in this case 1. you can it get it through a simple join query instead. for case 2: you can get the answer just y googling

Comment: the no. 1 is already answered..the only problem now is no. 2, i have no idea how to do it, any idea u want to give me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*...displays the title of the tape and number of times that a
>   specific tape has been borrowed. The input to the procedure is only
>   the specific id.*"

here's the sample Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE list_title_ntimes (IN my_id VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.Title, COUNT(*) totalCountBorrowed
    FROM    Tapes a
            LEFT JOIN   Tape_Specific_ID b
                ON a.TapesID = b.TapesID 
    WHERE   a.TapesID = my_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

if you want to get all without specifying the `ID`,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE list_title_ntimes ()
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.Title, COUNT(*) totalCountBorrowed
    FROM    Tapes a
            LEFT JOIN   Tape_Specific_ID b
                ON a.TapesID = b.TapesID 
    GROUP BY a.Title;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the first procedure doesn't work, i called the function "call list_title_ntimes('TS1'); error: it says that unknown column 'TS1' in the field list' ...

Comment: it doesn't work...error: unknown column 'TS1' in the 'field list'

Comment: ive chcked all the tables and all the fields and no missing...

Comment: 'TS1' is a literal string, so it has to be surrounded by single quotes -- unshifted double-quotes.  This is not interchangeable with the backtick, which is usually on the button to the left of the 1 key on the keyboard.  You will get the message you're seeing if you use backticks or or don't use quotes at all.

Comment: call list_title_ntimes('TS1') error:column "TapesID" in where clause is ambiguous. still a error..what should i do?

Comment: i was thinking that this problem is in referential integrity..could this be possible?

Comment: @NeilBryanCasinang try the update `WHERE   a.TapesID = my_id;`

Comment: @NeilBryanCasinang can you post the whole error message?

Comment: @JW: wat do you mean by update?   WHERE a.TapesID = my_id; is still the same with the first procedure that you have posted...

Comment: the reason i added `a.TapesID` is because it throws an exception `column "TapesID" in where clause is ambiguous`. now, you you execute the procedure, what is the full error message generated?

Comment: call list_title_ntimes('TS1');   
error: column "TapesID" in where clause is ambiguous.

Comment: yes, that is why add the alias of the table. drop the procedure and execute thsi once again, `DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE list_title_ntimes (IN my_id VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.Title, COUNT(*) totalCountBorrowed
    FROM    Tapes a
            LEFT JOIN   Tape_Specific_ID b
                ON a.TapesID = b.TapesID 
    WHERE   a.TapesID = my_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: it works but only problem is the argument in function calling is the TSpectID not the TapesID..

Comment: ive done with the number 1 procedure only number 2, can u help me?i really don't have idea..

Comment: i can help you with this but the problem is i dont understand some of your comments. there are some things which I think you dont tell us here. like this one `argument in function calling is the TSpectID not the TapesID` why `TSpectID`?

Comment: im done with that..the only problem now is the trigger(question no. 2)..honestly, i have no idea how to do it...